# Problem when installing openconnect using brew

Tags: homebrew, symlink, openconnect

I am stuck when trying to install "openconnect" using homebrew because I am not permitted to make the symbolic link to `/usr/local/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES`.
I am running Big Sur version 11.4.

Below follows what I have tried:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-5:Data Eigil$ brew uninstall --force openconnect

Uninstalling openconnect... (54 files, 2.8MB)

(base) MacBook-Pro-5:Data Eigil$ brew cleanup -s openconnect

Removing: /Users/Eigil/Library/Caches/Homebrew/openconnect--8.10... (971.3KB)

(base) MacBook-Pro-5:Data Eigil$ brew cleanup --prune-prefix

(base) MacBook-Pro-5:Data Eigil$ brew install openconnect

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 8 formulae.
==> Updated Casks
Updated 1 cask.

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openconnect/manifests/8.10
Already downloaded: /Users/Eigil/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c979ec1baea5847f748962ba42b95bce88cef90599731a131c5588090c9c066b--openconnect-8.10.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openconnect/blobs/sha256:9755c4ea66ed9c8aa1f1ee966c932ec2be37849887636d8f65a920f20c16ec55
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:9755c4ea66ed9c8aa1f1ee966c932ec2be37849887636d8f65a920f20c16ec55?
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openconnect--8.10.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/openconnect.mo
/usr/local/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link openconnect
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openconnect/8.10: 54 files, 2.8MB
```

The suggested solution doesn't work (still because I cannot write to `LC_MESSAGES`). `sudo` is not permitted on that directory neither.

```
ls -l /usr/local/share/locale/ca/
```

gives:

```
total 0

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  96 Jun 28 11:34 LC_MESSAGES/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew is not designed to work with `sudo`. You should never prepend `sudo` before command `brew`, which will change the ownership of some of the brew related files.

The consequence is that some of the files are not owned by you but by `root` now. You have to fix the permission.

```sh
# For x86 Mac
sudo chown -R "$(whoami):admin" /usr/local/*

# For M1 mac
sudo chown -R "$(whoami):admin" /opt/homebrew/*

# NOTE:
# * in /usr/local/* is used on purpose to only match the sub folders, files
# The command will take some time, wait patiently.
```

You'd better re-install `openconnect` after above fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work. I know that I should not use sudo on brew commands. Maybe I did that long time ago, but I didn't run into the consequence until now.